# Force overflow of table row into next row

Tags: html, css, jsx, tsx

I want to create a calendar component which displays the day on the top and the time on the left.
Looking at Google Calendar, they seem to be using absolute to put the events into the calendar, which I want to avoid.
The next best option to me seemed to be using a table. This option worked fine for the structure of the calendar, but now that I want to add events I have a problem:

Each row represents one hour and each row is 60px tall. Now if I add an event that lasts 75 minutes I need that event to overflow from one row to the next. But instead it just increases the height of the row where I added the event.

Is this behaviour enforced or can I circumvent it somehow?

Here is my current table code:

```
<table className="w-full">
        <caption className="sr-only">Calendar</caption>
        <tr className="sticky top-0">
          <td className="invisible" />
          {[...Array(days).keys()].map((day) => {
            return (
              <th scope="col" className="border-x bg-white">
                {getDayName(calculateDay(day), "en-US").slice(0, 3)}
              </th>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
        {[...Array(24).keys()].map((hour) => {
          return (
            <tr className="h-[60px] overflow-visible">
              <th scope="row" className="w-16 border">
                {hour === 0 ? null : `${hour.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:00`}
              </th>
              {[...Array(days).keys()].map((day) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    {day === 1 && hour === 3 ? (
                      <td className="h-[75px] overflow-visible border bg-red-300">
                        Hello
                      </td>
                    ) : (
                      <td className="border" />
                    )}
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
```

[image: Event "Hello" increases the height of the row instead of overflowing]

Comment: _"But instead it just increases the height of the row"_ - now guess again, _why_ Google uses absolute positioning for this ... and explain why you want to "avoid" that in the first place?

Comment: I can see why they used absolute, I just believe that it would be "better" to avoid absolute, because of for example accessibility. And yes you can of course achieve great accessibility with absolute, but I thought it would be easier to try something more accessible from the beginning. Furthermore I looked at another example which did use table, but had one table for each row, which didnt seem right either, but in that case each row was not one hour but one person.

Comment: What specific accessibility issues would that be then, in a case like this?

Comment: Okay let me ask differently. Is absolute, in your opinion, not only the best but also only option to realise this?

Comment: It is the easiest, I would say. It might not be the only one - depending on what/how much data exactly you need to display, you could for example also "divide" your 75 minute event into two elements, 60px and 15px tall, respectively, and place them into two table cells ... (accessibility-wise, that would probably be bad though.) Other stuff you could usually use to "drag" following elements up, like negative margins, probably won't work inside a table.

Comment: Alright. I wanted to try out negative margins, but they don't work. Adding to that the accessibility concerns, I should probably scrap that idea. One last idea: CSS grids, do you believe those would work, since they can structure my page like a table, but are not as strict from my understanding. Otherwise I'll try absolute.

Comment: Grid could work - but then you would have to manipulate the _formatting_ based on your data (like, how far does a cell in the grid actually need to stretch?) Plus, in terms of accessibility, I guess a grid would convey less semantics than a table would?

Comment: Oh yeah right, the semantics aspects would be lost anyway. Thanks for the feedback. I'll try switching to absolute.